# Perturbation in Euler-Heisenberg Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

If we use minimal subtraction to remove infinities, the effective Lagrangian of the background EM field is:

$$ \mathcal{L}_{EH} = -\dfrac{1}{4}F^2_{\mu\nu} - \dfrac{e^2}{32\pi^2}\int \dfrac{ds}{s}e^{is\epsilon - sm^2}[\dfrac{Re Cosh(esX)}{Im Cosh(esX)}F_{\mu\nu}\tilde{F}_{\mu\nu} - \dfrac{4}{e^2 s^2} - 2/3F^2_{\mu\nu}].  $$

Why is it non-perturbative in $e$? Does it not mean infinite 1-loop diagrams?

Comment: *Does it not mean infinite 1-loop diagrams?* I think they’re probably the same diagrams as for the [Schwinger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_effect), which I think can be derived from the E-H Lagrangian.